# ggvis multiple lines with tooltips

Tags: r, ggvis

I am trying to create an interactive Version of this plot:
[image: GGplot Graph]

So far I have the following code that creates an interactive plot but is not exactly what I am looking for:

```
#Create Data
library(ggvis)
set.seed(123)
tdat <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 50),
               time = rep(seq(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), length.out = 50, by = "day"), 2),
               val = c(cumsum(rnorm(50)) + 100,
                       cumsum(rnorm(50)) + 100))

# ggvis Code
# Function for the tooltip
getData <- function(dat){
    paste(paste("Time:", as.character(dat$time)),
    paste("Group:", as.character(dat$group)),
    paste("Value:", dat$val),
    sep = "<br />")
}

# Visualisation
tdat %>% ggvis(~time, ~val, stroke = ~group) %>% layer_lines(strokeWidth := 1) %>%
     layer_points(size = 1, fill = ~group) %>% add_tooltip(getData)
```

This results in the following plot:
[image: GGvis Plot]
There are however some issues:

1) I don't want to have points, just lines. Without the layer_points, there are no tooltips...

2) The variable time is a date but shows up as an integer. How can I fix the ugly number?

Thank you very much.

**Edit**

The field of the tooltip can be formated to date if it is coerced to a char before calling the ggvis function but it introduces other issues. For example, the x-axis does not shown properly.

Comment: Are you sure you cannot get tooltips without `layer_points`? I removed `layer_points` from your code and I still get tooltips.

Comment: @Pascal If you remove `layer_points` you just see one point throughout the line.

Comment: Exaclty, I would like to leave layer_points out, but I only get one tooltip.

Comment: Has your question changed to asking only about the points then? The bad thing about converting the date to character before running the `ggvis` function is that additional fixing is required for the gridlines and the x-axis labels.

Comment: True, actually, I will reformulate the question to make it clear that it hasn't really changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for both:

```
#Create Data
library(ggvis)
set.seed(123)
tdat <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:2], each = 50),
                   time = rep(seq(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), length.out = 50, by = "day"), 2),
                   val = c(cumsum(rnorm(50)) + 100,
                           cumsum(rnorm(50)) + 100))
```

For the getData function a bit of reverse engineering made me find the solution. Apparently if you divide the numeric date by 86400000 and add the origin of 1970-01-01 makes it work.

```
# ggvis Code
# Function for the tooltip
getData <- function(dat){

  paste(paste("Time:", as.Date(dat$time/86400000, origin='1970-01-01') ),
        paste("Group:", as.character(dat$group)),
        paste("Value:", dat$val),
        sep = "<br />")
}
```

As for the points, just setting the opacity to zero makes it work:

```
# Visualisation
tdat %>% ggvis(~time, ~val, stroke = ~group) %>% layer_lines(strokeWidth := 1) %>%
  layer_points(size = 1, fill = ~group, opacity := 0) %>% add_tooltip(getData)
```

Ouput:

[image]

Sorry for the bad output but this was the best I could get via a print screen.

Comment: Heureka! Nice idea with the opacity. Let's see if someone knows a nicer way of fixing the dates. So far a very useful workaround though! Thanks

Comment: Do you get the error that values in the middle (say for example 8th of February) are labelled using the data from the first entry?

Comment: @David Yeah unfortunately there is no fix for this as far as I know.